# How to get the value of a private member using reflection C# 4

Tags: reflection, c#-4.0, private, member

I am trying to get the private member's value (Text) from NumericUpDown.

```
 public class NumericUpDown
 {
      private TextBox Text;
      ...
      ...
 }
```

I am not understanding why it's not showing as a field. Maybe someone could clarify the difference between fields and members. If it was a field I have found that using reflection I can get it by:

```
 typeof(NumericUpDown).GetField("Text", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(this) As TextBox
```

but it's a member so I have to get the MemberInfo by:

```
 typeof(NumericUpDown).GetMember("Text", BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance).GetValue(0)
```

this does not return the value, but a string with the type. Which would make sense, because It's the value of the memberinfo, but I want the actual value of the actual object.

Is there any way of retrieving it like FieldInfo.GetValue(object)? Any help or suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `NumericUpDown.Text` is not a member, it is a property. And it is public. Please clarify which type and member you want to use.

Comment: @SevaTitov maybe my search is wrong. I originally found a _textBox, but I was unable to extract it. Is that what I'm looking for? I am searching for the TextBox. When I searched with reflection I found _textBox and Text and they both say that they are TextBox. Any light on this? Right now the only way I'm able to reference it is when it gets focus. Then in the event I grab the original source and set the textbox there, but this doesn't seem like the best way.

Comment: Ok. I thought your were using standard NumericUpDown from System.Windows.Forms. Apparently you are using some other library. In your definition `Text` _is_ a field. And you should be able to retrieve that using call `myType.InvokeMember("Text",     BindingFlags.GetField | BindingFlags.Instance |  indingFlags.NonPublic, null, myInstance, null);`

Comment: @SevaTitov Silverlight.I tried typeof(NumericUpDown).InvokeMember("Text", BindingFlags.GetProperty | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic, null, ctrl, null); and it gives me a MethodAccessException I'm not understanding it. I found a diagram too and I'm not crazy, the TextBox is Text and _text, both private. http://lh4.ggpht.com/_iM_rdx7nVGA/SR9_rUmDr0I/AAAAAAAAATo/avem0hemJGo/NUD4.png?imgmax=800

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because you are using Silverlight.

Quote:
[Silverlight reflection cannot be used to bypass access level restrictions and (for example) invoke private members.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7ykdhsy%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Comment: Interesting, did not know that.

Comment: Well this is good and bad. I know why I can't grab it, but I'm stuck with my hack for now, or until they expose that object. Thanks for shedding some light on the issue.